# Experiencing ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib' when I use Tensorflow GPU processing

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am experiencing `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'` while executing `from tensorflow.contrib.cudnn_rnn.python.ops import cudnn_rnn_ops` command in the `keras\layers\cudnn_recurrent.py`, line `425`. This issue is specific to Tensorflow **when using GPU processing**. No issues at all if I do not use GPU processing.

Here is my software stack:

```
 - OS: Windows 10
 - Python: 3.7.4
 - CUDA: 10.1
 - cuDNN: 7.5.0.56
 - tensorflow: 2.0.0
 - tensorflow-gpu: 2.0.0
 - keras: 2.3.1
```

Edit: To make it clearer, the only thing I changed in the code in order to use GPU processing (as my GPU supports CUDA) instead of CPU processing was using `keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM` class instead of `keras.layers.LSTM`. And of course, I have installed `tensorflow-gpu` package through `pipenv`.

Comment: Smth does not add up here. Are you using `tensorflow.keras` or just plain `keras`?

Comment: The latter one, using `keras` directly.

Comment: Seems that your version of keras relies on a mismatching version of Tensorflow. I would suggest running 'pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu tensorflow' and installing version 1 that contains tf.contrib with 'pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15'

Comment: This time got a different error as follows: `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'CudnnRNN' used by {{node cu_dnnlstm_1/CudnnRNN}}with these attrs: [seed=87654321, dropout=0, T=DT_FLOAT, input_mode="linear_input", direction="unidirectional", rnn_mode="lstm", is_training=true, seed2=0]
Registered devices: [CPU]
Registered kernels:
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_HALF]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]

  [[cu_dnnlstm_1/CudnnRNN]]`

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow 2.0 discontinued supporting contrib. You can learn more about it [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate).

Possibly, your code has been written for TF 1.* or was not ported properly.

Comment: The only line changed in the code in order to benefit from GPU processing is importing `keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM` instead of `keras.layers.LSTM`.

Comment: @talha06 I would than recommend filling a bug to TF repo. Meanwhile you can try `tf.compat.v1.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM` to check if that one works. Also, this issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25843 suggests that CuDNNLSTM can be picky about it's configurations

Comment: Can we combine `keras` and `tf.compat` layers?